# Condition on attribute in sass

Tags: css, sass

I want to apply style depending on condition on the typa attribute provided by html like this:

```
<img src="pf_brise_lame_bdef_034.jpg?itok=3vKP-E25" width="325" height="183" alt="Présentation de l'Association" title="Présentation de l'Association" loading="lazy" typeof="Image" class="lazy-hidden">
```

So I don't know how to write the condition into my scss file, here is the starting point:

```
   $attribut:[typeof="Image"];
                @if $attribut == [typeof="Image"]{
                background: transparent;
                  a{
                      display: none;
                  }
                  }
                  @else {
                  background: $gris-anthracite;
                    a{
                        display: initial;
                    }
                  }
```

what could be the right syntax to achieve this ? into a li element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SASS for this is unneeded. You can use vanilla CSS with attribute selectors. See the following example - images by default have no border, however here with the `typeof` attribute being assigned 'image' they will receive the defined border.

```css
img {
  border: none;
}
img[typeof='image'] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50' typeof='image' />
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/50' typeof='' />
```

**But if you're set on SASS...**

What you're trying to do in your example is simply setting a variable and then running a comparison on it.  However you need to wrap that variable in quotes for that to work.

```
$attribut: '[typeof="Image"]';
@if $attribut == '[typeof="Image"]' {
...
}
```

However this is just comparing the defined variable 'attribut' and in no way is defining a rule for images containing that attribute.  To do that I stand by my first suggestion, just using CSS.

Comment: ok. for my interest, what would be the syntax for condition on typeof ?

Comment: I edited my answer.